# Is there any way to create an object with attribute from multiple arrays?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON file which is a menu. So there is one array with pizza's and inside that array is a array called `ingredient` which contains the `id` from the ingredients.

So I want to create objects who has the attributes from the `pizza` arrays with the value from the `ingredient` array.

My error is below:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (out of START_OBJECT token)

I already created a object which only accesses to the `pizza` array.
In the code you can see how I tried to convert it.

**Code snippet**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
//File file = new File("path");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try
{
    JsonNode gesMenu = mapper.readValue(file, JsonNode.class);
    JsonNode jMenu = gesMenu.get("Menu");
    JsonNode gesIngredient = jMenu.get("ingredient");

    Ingredient[] cIngredient = mapper.convertValue(gesIngredient, Ingredient[].class);
    System.out.println(cIngredient[7].getDescription());;

    JsonNode gesPizza = jMenu.get("pizza");
    System.out.println("\n" + gesPizza);

    //These last two lines cause Errors
    Pizza2[] pPizza = mapper.convertValue(gesPizza, Pizza2[].class);
    System.out.println(pPizza[0]);

}
...
```

Here is a example of the JSON file:

```
{
  "menu" : {
    "pizza" : [
      {
        "nr" : 1,
        "description" : "Pizza Salami",
        "ingredient" : [
          {
            "id" : 0
          }
        ],
        "Picture" : "Salami.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `cIngredient[7].getDescription()` indicates that `Ingredient` is meant to have more properties than just an id. So parsing `[ { "id" : 0 } ]` into `Ingredient[]` probably won't work - you'd have to implement any lookups yourself if you want to "convert" an id into a fully fledged ingredient instance.

Comment: @Thomas, ingredient has 5 properties: id, description, priceSmall, priceMedium, priceBig.
And I want a object which includes the values from the ingredientArray too.

Pizza class properties: 
number, description, picture, id
The id in Pizza should be filled with the values from the JsonArray inside the pizzaArray so only the "id"

Comment: Well, as I said you'd have to implement those lookups yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the structure of JSON string you provide and what you mentioned in comment, there is a simple way to convert whole JSON string to nested POJOs as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyJsonObject myJsonObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyJsonObject.class);
System.out.println(myJsonObj.toString());
```

**Console output**

> MyJsonObject [menu=Menu [pizza=[Pizza [nr=1, description=Pizza Salami, ingredient=[Ingredient [id=0, description=null, priceSmall=null, priceMedium=null, priceBig=null]], picture=Salami.jpg]]]]

Whereas the nested POJOs look like:

```
class MyJsonObject {
    private Menu menu;
    //general getters and setters
    //toString()
}

class Menu {
    private List<Pizza> pizza;
    //general getters and setters
    //toString()
}

class Pizza {
    private int nr;
    private String description;
    private List<Ingredient> ingredient;
    @JsonProperty("Picture")
    private String picture;
    //general getters and setters
    //toString()
}

class Ingredient {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String priceSmall;
    private String priceMedium;
    private String priceBig;
    //general getters and setters
    //toString()
}
```

Then you can access both `pizza` or `ingredient` JSON arrays easily just like operating objects in Java!

Comment: Allright, I will try that out. And tell you later if I messed it up, or not :)

Comment: @BlitzDodo What do you mean "combine both information like a Database"? Colud you provide some example? But I think this not the original question you asked.

Comment: well you're right, my question is solved, what I now mean is a new question, but before I ask it here I try my luck ;)